# Perl: how to split strings of mixture of Chinese/English/numbers by space?

Tags: regex, string, perl

The input and expected outputs look like the following:

```
今天天气好              ->    今 天 天 气 好
今天123天气好           ->    今 天 1 2 3 天 气 好
今天foo天气bar好        ->    今 天 foo 天 气 bar 好
foobar123              ->    foobar 1 2 3
```

Essentially, i'd like to have English words intact and Chinese/number spaced out.

I started with the following but got stuck on how to trim spaces within a substring of a string.

```
my $input_uttr = decode('UTF-8', $args{u})
my @token_list = split(/(?<=.)/, $input_uttr);                                                                                                         
my $token_uttr = join(' ', @token_list);                                                                                                               
$token_uttr =~ s/[a-z][\sa-z]+[a-z]/ /g;
```

Specifically, the last line would take all the alphabetical strings out, e.g.,

```
今天foo天气bar好      ->    今 天   天 气   好
```

Is there a way to fix this? 
Alternatively, i wonder if there is way to trim space within substrings of a string:

```
今 天 f o o 天 气 b a r 好      ->            今 天 foo 天 气 bar 好
```

Or are there other better ways of handling this problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can search for this regex:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z])(?<=[\p{L}\p{N}])|(?<!^)(?![a-zA-Z])(?=[\p{L}\p{N}])
```

And replace by:

```
" "
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uJ6oX4/2)

Flags used:

- `g` for global
- `u` for unicode support

This regex uses alternation to check if left hand or right hand side of any character is unicode character or number but NOT ascii letter `[A-Za-z]`. If match is found then replacement is performed using a space.

#### Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use utf8;

my $str = '今天天气好
今天123天气好
今天foo天气bar好
foobar123';

$str =~ s/(?<![a-zA-Z])(?<=[\p{L}\p{N}])|(?<!^)(?![a-zA-Z])(?=[\p{L}\p{N}])/ /mg;

print $str . "\n";
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
今 天 天 气 好
今 天 1 2 3 天 气 好
今 天 foo 天 气 bar 好
foobar 1 2 3
```

Comment: You should always mention `u` flag in these cases.

Comment: Thanks I added it my answer but wasn't sure if perl also needs it.

Comment: I'm not too sure about the best practice. Perl has the flag http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Character-set-modifiers, but I see people recommending setting utf8 http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html (which is probably the better alternative).

Comment: do you mind putting a bit of code snippet for this? because i can't get this compiled: my $token_uttr =~ s/(?<![a-zA-Z])(?<=[\p{L}\p{N}])|(?<!^)(?![a-zA-Z])(?=[\p{L}\p{N}])/ /gu ------ Bareword found where operator expected at **** line 32, near "s/(?<![a-zA-Z])(?<=[\p{L}\p{N}])|(?<!^)(?![a-zA-Z])(?=[\p{L}\p{N}])/ /gu"
syntax error ....

Comment: @nhahtdh: Yes I also found out that `use utf8;` is preferred way (see updated answer)

Comment: it works! may take some time for me to understand that long regex :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd do:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use utf8;

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @res = split(/(?<![a-z])|(?![a-z])/, $_);
    say join ' ', @res;
}

__DATA__
今天天气好
今天123天气好
今天foo天气bar好
foobar123
```

**Output:**

```
今 天 天 气 好
今 天 1 2 3 天 气 好
今 天 foo 天 气 bar 好
foobar 1 2 3
```

Comment: This works! Thanks! I don't get 'use utf8' work though -- if i input text in a terminal, the output in terminal is not displayed properly.

Comment: But won't this also split on space or all other special punctuation characters. I though requirement is to add a space only for numeric or non-ascii letters.